# Duplicate Entry during Android gradle build in Task :transformClassesWithJarMergingAndroidTest

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-multidex

I'm getting the following exception when building my Android app with Gradle:

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForGoogleGermanDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/hamcrest/BaseDesc
```

The problem seems to be that in my build.gradle file I have declared:

```
testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3'
```

However, I need both dependencies for unit tests and integration tests. How to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was that another jar (Mockito) included `hamcrest-core` as a transitive dependency. This module contains all classes under the package name `org.hamcrest.*`. Hence the conflict. The solution was:

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
```

As described here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html Chapter 23.4.7

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `exclude` parameter for repeated entries.

```
androidTestCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:1.3' {
    exclude module: 'BaseDesc'
}
```

Comment: That solved the error above but now the conflict happens with class BaseDescription. This way I would have to exclude every class in the package org.hamcrest separately..

Comment: Yeah, that's true. You will need to do that.may be try with `org.hamcrest.*` wildcard character.

Answer (score -3):

```
 buildTypes {
       release {
          multiDexEnabled true;
      }
 }
```

try this this should work

Comment: Tried it but without sucess

Comment: Why do people seem to think multidex solves every Android problem ever!